# Find maximum and minimum value of points within a polygon buffer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, point, point-in-polygon

I have a series of 500m buffer zones along a polyline. I also have a series of points following the line, each point represents a 10m x 10m cell. I calculated the values of a field in each point known as "F18".

I want to find the average, maximum and minimum values in F18 for all points within each buffer zone and add fields to the attribute table of the buffer for each.

ArcGIS 10.1, arcinfo license.

Comment: Are you looking for a scripting answer or just a workflow on how to do the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing as you have Info (Advanced) level of license you can use the cool geoprocessing toys.

Get the values of the polygons onto the points either by spatial join, [identity](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Identity/00080000000n000000/) or [intersect](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Intersect/00080000000p000000/). I think that [intersect](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Intersect/00080000000p000000/) would be my choice. This will generate a point for each intersection i.e. if a point falls in more than one buffer then there will be one instance for each buffer it intersects.

To turn this into a table with min, mean and max you can use [frequency](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001w000000) or [summary statistics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Summary_Statistics/00080000001z000000/), I use summary statistics mostly so I have a bias toward that one.

The OID field for the polygon is a 'case' field which will give one row in the table for each polygon with the min, mean and max values of the intersecting points listed in the row.

To get the values in the table back to the polygon use "[join by attributes](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s0000002q000000)" using the OID for the polygon to join to the table 'case' field, then export to make it permanent.

This procedure can be used in a model, Python scripting or ArcObjects as a geoprocessor... whichever one floats your boat.

Comment: Does exactly what I need and can be inputted into a model or python scripting which means I can automate it for many polygons and points.

Answer (score 4):

I had a tool I made that basically did this, so I just tweaked it a little to fit what you need.

It's called Calculate Point Statistics, and you can download it here:

http://ianbroad.com/arcgis-toolbox-calculate-point-statistics-polygon-arcpy/

Source code:

http://ianbroad.com/download/script/CalculatePointStatistics.py

It takes an input Polygon and Point feature class and uses a selected field to find the minimum, maximum, and average of the points and adds the results to the polygon feature. It skips any null values. It will work with ArcGIS 10.1+

Here's a screenshot of the parameters:
[image]

Comment: This is very useful, I have downloaded it and will use it.

Comment: I added the source code to my post.